# How to import only the most recent table from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to import data from GCS into BigQuery.

Initially to do this I have created a table in BigQuery, selected GCS as the storage option, and then used a wildcard after "test-", so "test-*". However, this is summing all of the data together from each table and thus containing duplicates. There is no field in the individual csv files which defines it's upload date/time, so I am unable to filter out the duplicates using a WHERE clause when using the wildcard.

```
gs://analytics_test/sales_data-test-2023_12_21_09_00_10_894349-000000000000.csv
gs://analytics_test/sales_data-test-2023_12_22_09_00_10_894349-000000000000.csv
gs://analytics_test/sales_data-test-2023_12_23_09_00_10_894349-000000000000.csv
gs://analytics_test/sales_data-test-2023_12_24_09_00_10_894349-000000000000.csv
```

Is there a way to only import the latest csv file, which is uploaded at the same time each day?

The simplest way in my mind would be to just import the tables in a similar way as the Google Analytics 4 connection to BigQuery automatically does, which is

"Within each dataset, a table named events_YYYYMMDD is created each day if the Daily export option is enabled."

However, I am unsure how to do this with the naming convention above, as it appears to not use the required paritioning format.

Thanks in advance for any guidance offered.

My method of testing is explained above.

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest that you create a Cloud Function that is triggered by the arrival of the new CSV file in your GCS.  Your Cloud Function will be passed the identity of the file and will be invoked only/immediately when the data has been uploaded.  Your Cloud Function could then load the data into your table from the named file.  In this story, there is no need to find the "latest" file ... as you will be told when the file is created.